# Access the glassfish server web application remotely

Tags: glassfish, redhat

I am able to access an application on glassfish server locally via `http://localhost:8080/domain1` or       `http://<machine-ip>:8080/domain1`. However, I am unable to access it from another remote machine.

When I put `http://<machine-ip>:8080/domain1` in a browser, connection timed out.

Firewall is off on both machines and I have also add machine-ip to /etc/hosts file. I can ping glassfish server machine    I am using redhat enterprise 6.3 linux on which glassfish is installed.

Please tell how to access it via IP. DO we need to change any configuration file?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

-Sam

Answer (score 0):

This  might be a problem because of Selinux policy being in enforcing mode.
Try changing it to passive or disabled mode and then try accessing your server.